# How to partially await nested promises in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have to make 3 main API calls (A1, B1 and C1) and 2 auxiliary API calls (A2 and B2). These are their dependencies:

- C1 must await both A1 and B1
- A2 must await A1
- B2 must await B1

This works but is not the right approach because I don't need to wait for B1 to finish before I can call A2 (or for A1 to finish before I can call B2). Note: `trigger()` returns a promise.

```
const a1 = A1.trigger();
const b1 = B1.trigger();

await Promise.all([a1, b1]);
A2.trigger(); // should happen earlier
B2.trigger(); // should happen earlier
C1.trigger();
```

I guess I could do this:

```
async function handleA() {
  const a1 = await A1.trigger();
  A2.trigger();
  return a1;
}
async function handleB() {
  const b1 = await B1.trigger();
  B2.trigger();
  return b1;
}

await Promise.all([handleA(), handleB()]);
C1.trigger();
```

In this case, it works because I don't need to worry about A2, B2 or C1, otherwise I'd need to start nesting functions and it might get hairy.

Is there a better approach or is this the best way to do it?

Comment: In what language? `await` was introduced by C# and adopted by other languages. The keyword may be the same but the specifics differ from one language to the next. This looks like Javascript

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed. I've just added the JS tag

Comment: You can use `then` instead of `await` to construct the chain you want, eg  `a1.then((value)=>.a2.trigger());`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `await` syntax is to make asynchronous programming behave more like synchronous programming, which makes this interwoven execution unnecessarily hard. It's pretty simple if you forget about `await`:

```
const a1 = A1.trigger();
const b1 = B1.trigger();

a1.then(res => A2.trigger(res));
b1.then(res => B2.trigger(res));
Promise.all([a1, b1]).then(res => C1.trigger(res));
```

Comment: Amen to that.
This can be even more succinct `a1.then(A2.trigger)`, etc. And `Promise.all([a1, b1]).then(C1.trigger)`

Comment: @thedude Depends on whether you need to care about context binding or not; I'm providing the safe option here.

Comment: Thanks, I was so hellbent on using await that I didn't realize it's not always the best tool for the job. 